# Datatable if statement in row array

Tags: codeigniter, if-statement, datatable

so i have used a datatable in codeigniter that show all row[] arrays that i have queried now my problem is that, how can i put a condition statement inside a row[] array i have tried every possible way that it could fit but an error would state that i could not define an if statement inside the row[] here is my code:

```
foreach ($list as $foo_app) {
       $ApplicationNo++;
       $row = array();

       $row[] = $foo_app->ApplicationNo;
       $row[] = $foo_app->UserId;
       $row[] = $foo_app->FirstName.''.$foo_app->LastName;
       $row[] = $foo_app->PlateNo;
       $row[] = $foo_app->DateApplied;
       $row[] = if (.$foo_app->Status_Application. === "In-Active") {
        <b class="w3-padding w3-gray w3-hover-white w3-round-xxlarge">
        }
        elseif (.$foo_app->Status_Application. === "Accepted") {
        <b class="w3-padding w3-green w3-hover-white w3-round-xxlarge">
       }
       elseif (.$foo_app->Status_Application. === "Denied") {
        <b class="w3-padding w3-red w3-hover-white w3-round-xxlarge">
       };
       $row[] = '<div style="text-align: center;">&#8369;'.$foo_app->AmountFinanced.'</div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write the if clause first, then add the result to row[] like this:

```
$html='';    
if ($foo_app->Status_Application. === "In-Active") {
    $html='<b class="w3-padding w3-gray w3-hover-white w3-round-xxlarge">';
    }
    elseif ($foo_app->Status_Application. === "Accepted") {
    $html='<b class="w3-padding w3-green w3-hover-white w3-round-xxlarge">';
   }
   elseif ($foo_app->Status_Application. === "Denied") {
    $html='<b class="w3-padding w3-red w3-hover-white w3-round-xxlarge">';
};

$row[]=$html;
```

Comment: For undefined $html : may be it's not going in any of the if-else block , decalare $html = '' or $html = null , above if block

Comment: I think you need to work on your array structure, but I'm not familiar with datatable

Comment: ahhhh okay.. hahah null declaration is fine.. can i ask why we need to declare the variable with null first?

Comment: one should define a variable before assign to other variable .   As in your code $html is defined in "if else if block" and probably as per conditions of block all results in false and $html variable is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

While compare string you can use string functions

```
$html = "";
if (!strcasecmp($foo_app->Status_Application,"In-Active")) {
    $html='<b class="w3-padding w3-gray w3-hover-white w3-round-xxlarge">';
    }
    elseif (!strcasecmp($foo_app->Status_Application,"Accepted")) {
    $html='<b class="w3-padding w3-green w3-hover-white w3-round-xxlarge">';
   }
   elseif (!strcasecmp($foo_app->Status_Application,"Denied")) {
    $html='<b class="w3-padding w3-red w3-hover-white w3-round-xxlarge">';
};
```

$row[]=$html;

Comment: !strcasecmp what is this for?

Comment: comparing string with ignoring case , and if the string match it returns 0 so !strcasecmp like !0 to run the if condition on success match found